# Nested Parent Grouping with RDLC

Tags: reporting-services

I'm trying to add groupings to my tablix. I was able to add a parent grouping and it would add in a new header and it works fine but my table is very long so I'm trying to nest the grouping value ontop of the collection.

Current grouping settings

Before Groupings

```
Date    Description
Jan     Description A
Feb     Description A
Jan     Description B
Feb     Description B
```

With Parent Grouping

```
Client Date Description
  A    Jan  Description A
       Feb  Description A
  B    Jan  Description B
       Feb  Description B
```

What I would like

```
       Date Description
       Client - A
       Jan  Description A
       Feb  Description A
       Client - B
       Jan  Description B
       Feb  Description B
```

I was wondering does RDLC support this type of grouping, if so may I ask how would I do that?

Comment: Yes, the technique is the same as adding a sub-total row, you just add it above the detail instead of below and don't include any subtotals.  Google "SSRS subtotal tutorial" for numerous examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to modify the default layout of the tablix to achieve the look you want. My dataset is slightly different than yours in that I'm showing a value instead of a description but the technique is the same.

Select your tablix and at the bottom of the design window in Visual Studio find the "Row Groups" box. Now select the drop-down arrow on the details group and add a Parent Group. Make sure to check the "Add group header" option in the dialog box.

[image: new tablix parent group]

Then go back to the "Row Groups" box and select the drop-down arrow in the details group again and this time select "Group properties". Add a new group expression on your month field.

[image: details group properties]

You will now have a tablix that looks like your initial example with an additional row inside of the parent grouping (this is the group header row).

[image: initial tablix design]

First select the parent group column (in my case it is ASSIGNMENT) and delete it. Then select the two cells in the parent group header row, right click, and select "Merge cells". Then set the value of this cell to be an expression that will show your header text. In my case I've used:

```
="Assignment group - " + Fields!ASSIGNMENT.Value
```

The final design of your tablix will look similar to this:

[image: final tablix design]

and the output looks like this:

[image: nested group output]

Of course you'll probably want to tweak it and make it look a bit nicer than that. This is just a quick & dirty example.